# Calculus: Proving an inequality equation with AM–GM inequality

Tags: calculus

I was given a task to prove the following inequality equation:
$$
\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a} \geq 3 \quad,\quad \text{for $a,b,c \gt 0$}
$$
A hint was also given: The [Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) equations should be used to help to prove the task.

I've tried several methods with using the AM-GM means, but to no avail.
For example, I reached the equation:
$$
6 \leq \frac{a+c}{b} + \frac{b+c}{a} + \frac{a+b}{c}
$$
Which translates also to:
$$
6abc \leq a^2c + ac^2 + b^2c + bc^2 +a^2b + ab^2
$$

When trying with a different method, I concluded that:
$$
27 \leq \frac{1}{a^2bc} + \frac{1}{ab^2c} + \frac{1}{abc^2}
$$

I don't know what am I missing.
I could use your advice/hint with this task. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let our three numbers be $x$, $y$, and $z$. Note that $xyz=1$. By AM-GM we have 
$$\frac{x+y+z}{3}\ge 1^{1/3}.$$

Comment: Splendid trick! I don't understand how I missed it! Thanks..!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Who are the elements of the sequence for the AM-GM means? Are they $(a,b,c)$ or $(\frac{a}{b},\frac{b}{c},\frac{c}{a})$ ?

Comment: In the above solution, we are to take $x=a/b$, $y=b/c$, and $z=c/a$.

Comment: Can we consider those numbers to constitute a series/sequence? Is it valid to do so in Calculus..? I thought that the numbers of a sequence should have a mathematical relationship between them, but the numbers `{x,y,z}` don't seem to have any relation with each other.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\geq3\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{b}\frac{b}{c}\frac{c}{a}}=3
$$

Comment: I appreciate your help too!